# ListView 2 rows and icon per Item in Android

Tags: android, android-listview

Hy,
I want to add an icon and 2 rows in one item of ListView. First will be values and second will be values2

```
String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
String[] values2 = new String[] `enter code here`{ "Android2", "iPhone2",        "WindowsMobile2",
            "Blackberry2", "WebOS2", "Ubuntu2", "Windows72", "Max OS  X2",
            "Linux2", "OS/22" };
```

My xml for list is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My xml for each row is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="22px"
    android:layout_height="22px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
    android:layout_marginRight="10px"
    android:layout_marginTop="4px"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="20px" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+id/label" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And my code is :

```
 public class listaNoua extends ListActivity {
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android", "iPhone", "WindowsMobile",
            "Blackberry", "WebOS", "Ubuntu", "Windows7", "Max OS X",
            "Linux", "OS/2" };
    String[] values2 = new String[] { "Android2", "iPhone2", "WindowsMobile2",
            "Blackberry2", "WebOS2", "Ubuntu2", "Windows72", "Max OS X2",
            "Linux2", "OS/22" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>  (this,R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label2, values2);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

If i add :

```
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.rowlayout,   R.id.label2, values2 , R.id.label, values);
```

The code does not work

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: see simplelistadapter for more complex binding (basically a list of ids and a list of items (though that works on cursors only, which would imply the use of a matrixcursor somewhere)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use list custom adapter. You can find good some example here

http://www.learn-android.com/2011/11/22/lots-of-lists-custom-adapter/

I think you forget the orientation for LinearLayout at your the row XML. The issue is that linear layout by default has "horizontal" orientation. The row should be as below to show all 3 items in the list.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="22dp"
    android:layout_height="22dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
</ImageView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it gives me the error The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(listaNoua, int, int, String[], int, String[]) is undefined  , and the first text is false and second text it`s what it should be (android2 , iphone 2)

Comment: And how should i do that ? Every attempt failed

Comment: customize this adapter: 
https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/blob/master/src/com/fedorvlasov/lazylist/LazyAdapter.java

Answer (score 5):

You can use SimpleAdapter for this.

```
    List<Map<String, ?>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, ?>>();
    data.add(createRow("Android", "Android2"));
    data.add(createRow("iPhone", "iPhone"));

    String[] from = {"value1", "value2"};
    int[] to = {R.id.label, R.id.label2};

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.item_layout, from, to);
```

and the function for creating a row

```
private Map<String, ?> createRow(String value1, String value2) {
    Map<String, String> row = new HashMap<String, String>();
    row.put("value1", value1);
    row.put("value2", value2);
    return row;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Android already comes with a predefined XML layout for this called [`simple_list_item_2`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_2.xml) so you don't have to write your own Adapter or write your own layout file.

You just need to override `getView` and set values for the already pre-defined `android.R.id.text1` and `android.R.id.text2` TextViews in the already-existing `simple_list_item_2` layout.

```
ArrayAdapter<MyObject> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<MyObject>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, result) {
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

        text1.setText(result.get(position).OperatingSystem);
        text2.setText(result.get(position).Platform);
        return view;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick for me. You might want to point out that `result` is  of type `MyObject[]` and holds the objects to add. Alternatively, one could drop this parameter altogether and add individual objects with `adapter.add()` or `adapter.addAll()`. Inside `getView()`, list items can then be accessed with `getItem(position)`.